# Schema markup for logo

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have this markup for Dentist https://schema.org/Dentist

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Dentist">

    // address is ok
    <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">asdfd sf412</span>
        <span itemprop="postalCode">12345</span>
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">sadfsdf</span>
    </span>

    // this fails
    <span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="logo.gif'; ?>"  />
    </span>

</div>
```

When trying to test code for `itemprop="logo"` https://schema.org/logo 
Google testing gives me error: **"A value for the url field is required."**
What am I missing?

I don't want logo to be visible on page, thats why I have put it as meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in Google’s SDTT is about the `Dentist` item, not about the `ImageObject` item. You can see this from the nesting level, the `url` row is on the same level as `logo` and `address`.

So adding a `url` property to the `Dentist` item would get rid of the error.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Dentist">

  <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">asdfd sf412</span>
    <span itemprop="postalCode">12345</span>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">sadfsdf</span>
  </span>

  <span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <link itemprop="url" href="logo.gif" />
  </span>

  <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/" />

</div>
```

I changed the `meta` to `link`, because HTML5 and Microdata require that you use `link` (instead of `meta`) if the value is a URI.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if you are looking for a **JSON-LD** format, look over the below code and give it a shot.

```
"publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Lokaci",
    "url": "https://lokaci.com",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/lokaci/image/upload/v1580448186/logo/lokaci_logo_black-corp-comp_nzkooj.png"
    }
  },
```

Here is the full code if you wanna have a look, the **schema micro-data** was about a news article.

------------------full JSON-LD format below ----------------

```
    {
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "url": "https://lokaci.com/news/Diwali-Countdown-Offer-A-Brothers-Gift",
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Lokaci",
    "url": "https://lokaci.com",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/lokaci/image/upload/v1580448186/logo/lokaci_logo_black-corp-comp_nzkooj.png"
    }
  },
  "dateline": "Laxminagar Delhi, 26 October 2019",
  "headline": "Diwali Countdown Offer: A Brother’s Gift",
  "mainEntityOfPage": "https://lokaci.com/newsroom",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Lokaci",
    "logo": "https://res.cloudinary.com/lokaci/image/upload/v1580448186/logo/lokaci_logo_black-corp-comp_nzkooj.png"
  },
  "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/lokaci/image/upload/v1575284148/Newsroom/A-One-Salon-Lokaci-wins-Oppo-phone_dfvzdl.jpg",
  "datePublished": " 26 October 2019",
  "dateModified": " 26 October 2019",
  "wordCount": 165,
  "keywords": "Lokaci, News"
}
```